# Python/Selenium: How to automatic press to button "Next" while its on the screen?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm writing autotest on Selenium, using python. 
After call a window, tooltip displayed on the screen. There are 27 steps, to complete tutorial (27 tooltips). Tooltips displayed one by one. There are the "Next" button on every tooltip (got same xpath for every step). 
How can I make selenium click on the "Next" button, while its displayed on the screen?

```
step1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/button')
step1.click()
print "Step 1 = OK"

step2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/button')
step2.click()
print "Step 2 = OK"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Expected Conditions functionality in selenium to wait for the visibility of an element.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

wd_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)

confirm1 = wd_wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/button')))
confirm1.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The help shows the following:

```
>>> help(driver.find_element_by_xpath)
Help on method find_element_by_xpath in module selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver:

find_element_by_xpath(xpath) method of selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver instance
    Finds an element by xpath.

    :Args:
     - xpath - The xpath locator of the element to find.

    :Returns:
     - WebElement - the element if it was found

    :Raises:
     - NoSuchElementException - if the element wasn't found

    :Usage:
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/td[1]')
```

So you could try to click the button in a loop until a `NoSuchElementException` occurs.